# XML Schema element required depending on enumeration value

Tags: xsd

Is there a way to require an element depending on the enumeration value entered for another element?

Basically, what I'm trying to do is have an user interface type defined by an enumeration. Depending on the interface type, some fields may or may not be required.

I understand this could be achieved either by making the elements optional, and handling the conditional logic in the Code, or by making different complex types for every possible interface type. However, I want the rules to be apparent to anyone reading the schema, so the Code solution wouldn't be ideal, and adding a ton of complex types, even though they share most of their required fields in common, would add a lot more to the xml parsing logic.

Is it possible to have all this logic contained in the schema to simplify validation and parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of conditional mandatory/optional element inclusion is not possible with XSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `RelaxNG`.

You will have a good technical data interface with this kind of schema (describing exactly the structure you want, with a tool like `Jing` for validation).

And then, if you want to use object mapping, you can use `Trang` to convert your RelaxNG schema to an XML Schema (the XML Schema will be little more loosy, the true data interface beeing described in RelaxNG).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll look into RelaxNG, but for now I'm going to stick with the standard XML schema, because the schemas I'm designing are intended to be exposed to 3rd party developers. I want to stick to an industry standard schema format instead of having them learn something new, even if it should be syntactically simple to understand. I'll definitely keep it in mind for internal schemas though.